# Inject Service to Guard - Nestjs

Tags: node.js, authentication, nestjs, passport.js

I have the following global guard:

authorization.guard.ts

```
import { ExecutionContext, Injectable } from "@nestjs/common"
import { Reflector } from "@nestjs/core"
import { AuthGuard } from "@nestjs/passport"

@Injectable()
export class AuthorizationGuard extends AuthGuard(["azure-ad"]) {
  public constructor(private readonly reflector: Reflector) {
    super()
  }

  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
    const isPublic = this.reflector.get<boolean>(
      "isPublic",
      context.getHandler(),
    )

    if (isPublic) {
      return true
    }

    const req = context.switchToHttp().getRequest()
    if(req.headers.isbypass){
      //help needed
    }


    const result = (await super.canActivate(context)) as boolean
    await super.logIn(req)
    return result
  }
}
```

and the following auth module and strategy:

```
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { PassportModule } from "@nestjs/passport";
import { UsersModule } from "modules/users/users.module";
import { AzureADStrategy } from "./azureAD.strategy";
import { SessionSerializer } from "./session.serializer";

@Module({
    imports: [PassportModule, UsersModule],
    providers: [AzureADStrategy, SessionSerializer],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

```
import {
    BearerStrategy,
    IBearerStrategyOption,
    ITokenPayload,
    VerifyCallback,
} from "passport-azure-ad";
import {
    Inject,
    Injectable,
    OnModuleInit,
    UnauthorizedException,
} from "@nestjs/common";
import passport = require("passport");
import { UsersService } from "modules/users/users.service";
import env from "../../config";

const tenantId = env.TENANT_ID;
const clientID = env.CLIENT_ID || "";

const azureCredentials: IBearerStrategyOption = {
//
};

@Injectable()
export class AzureADStrategy extends BearerStrategy implements OnModuleInit {
    onModuleInit() {
        passport.use("azure-ad", this);
    }

    constructor(
        @Inject(UsersService) private usersService: UsersService
    ) {
        super(
            azureCredentials,
            async (token: ITokenPayload, done: VerifyCallback) => {
                if (Date.now() / 1000 > token.exp) {
                    return done(new UnauthorizedException("access token is expired"));
                }

                const tokenUsername = token?.preferred_username?.slice(0, 9);
                const tokenAppId = !tokenUsername && token?.azp;

                if (!tokenUsername && !tokenAppId) {
                    return done(new UnauthorizedException("Missing User"));
                }

                let user;

                if (tokenUsername) {
                        try {
                            user = await this.usersService.getUser(
                                tokenUsername
                            );

                            if (!user) {
                                return done(
                                    new UnauthorizedException("User is not a test user")
                                );
                            }
                        } catch (err) {
                            return done(err);
                        }

                    user.tz = tokenUsername;
                } else {
                    user.appId = tokenAppId;
                }

                return done(null, user, token);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

The guard is defined globally using:

```
  const reflector = app.get(Reflector);
  app.useGlobalGuards(
        new AuthorizationGuard(reflector),
    );
```

And the auth module is imported in app.module.ts:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    AuthModule,
    ...
]
```

Now, for the question.

I would like to have a way to "backdoor" the global authorization by checking if req.headers.isbypass exists in the request's headers, and if it does use userService in authorizationGuard, so i can inject the user from the DB to req.user myself and continue the request.
How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the `app.useGlobalGuards()` to be a global guard provider, adding

```js
{
  provider: APP_GUARD,
  useClass: AuthorizationGuard,
}
```

Into the `providers` of your `AppModule` so that Nest handles all of the DI for you. From there, it's just adding the `UsersService` to the `constructor` like you already have for the `Reflector`

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthorizationGuard extends AuthGuard(["azure-ad"]) {
  public constructor(
    private readonly reflector: Reflector,
    private readonly usersService: UsersServce
  ) {
    super()
  }

  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
    const isPublic = this.reflector.get<boolean>(
      "isPublic",
      context.getHandler(),
    )

    if (isPublic) {
      return true
    }

    const req = context.switchToHttp().getRequest()
    if(req.headers.isbypass){
      //help needed
    }


    const result = (await super.canActivate(context)) as boolean
    await super.logIn(req)
    return result
  }
}
```

Comment: I get this error `Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AuthorizationGuard (Reflector, ?).` when adding the userService in constructor, any idea why?

Comment: @alucard does it know the name of the missing dep, or is it reported as `dependency`?

Comment: I found it, its because in userService, you may have dep inject like prisma service, jwtService etc, make sure this is exported from usermodule, or add their dep in app module in provider: [] setting